# How can I count different mysql rows in one database request?

Tags: mysql, pdo, count

```
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ;');
$total = $pdo->rowCount();  
echo $total;
```

The result is for example `3`.

But I have a column named "done" in mySQL database where the possible value is `1` or `0`.

I want now to count all rows with the value `1`. So if there are for example in total `9` elements in the database and from them three items with the value `1` then the result should be:

`3/9`

I know only know how to do this with a second database request

```
 $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE done = "1"  ;');
 $done = $pdo->rowCount();  

 echo $done."/".$total;
```

But I was wondering if this is possible in just one database request.

Comment: Careful , `rowcount()` is not consistent across all databases for SELECT statements - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports expressions in SUM, so if your looking to get a total count and a filtered count at the same time you can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount, SUM(`done`=1) as completeCount FROM `data`
```

You can also add in the "not done" count if needed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount, SUM(`done`=1) as completeCount, SUM(`done`=0) as incompleteCount FROM `data`
```

With your code:

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(`done`=1) as complete FROM `data`';
$pdo = $db->query($query);
$data = $pdo->fetch(); // Uses PDO::FETCH_BOTH by default  
echo $data['complete']."/".$data['total'];
```

Comment: Looks good. How do I execute the result? `$result = $pdo->fetchAll();` and then `foreach ($result as $row) { echo  $row['totalCount'];}`?

Comment: I tested it, but not getting the result. I must make a mistake somewhere. Let you know if I solved it

Comment: @Jarla added an example

Answer (score 4):

Try this for the query, and get the info from the results (not row count)

```
SELECT `done`, count(*) as `numrows` FROM `data` GROUP BY `done`;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested it. Just cannot get from there to  3/9. I get something like 0101010101

Comment: You're probably echoing the object itself, not the results. You need to fetch the results.